# iOS 13 How to check user is given only Always allow location permission

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ios13

In my application, I want to check whether user is granted location permission "Always allow". Because I am doing kind of location sharing as like WhatsApp location live sharing.

Actually the test case is, when we change the location permission status to "while using the app" in the app settings and check the status on button click inside the app, I am getting "authorised Always" value.

```
  func isAlwaysPermissionGranted() -> Bool{
    let aStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if aStatus == .authorizedAlways {
        return true
    }
     return false
  }
```

If we have "while using the app" permission, I can't differentiate the "While Using the app" and "Always". Both are having same enum values that is "authorizedAlways".

**But in WhatsApp, If I changed the location permission to "While Using the App" and tried to share my live location, WhatsApp shows one alert to change the location permission in App Settings.**

I want to do same like that.

Kindly help me to different in code level.

Comment: please share more code for better understanding. Could you please update your question with your whole `CLLocationManager` configuration? Did you implement delegate methods like `didChangeAuthorization` ?

Comment: Have you requested "always"?  If so then you will get "always" because you have provisional always authentication even though the settings shows that you have "when in use". Once iOS prompts the user to upgrade to always or keep when in use you will start seeing the actual permission.

Comment: this helps ↓
https://medium.com/swlh/location-permission-in-ios-13-f9e10917c05e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I removed `CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` from the code.

If you request for Always Authorization, CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus becomes authorizedAlways.

I made it like if app wants always access, user has to go to settings and give the always permission manually

Comment: iOS 13 and 14 changed it and before requesting always you have to request whenInUse.

Answer (score 2):

you can check it in **didChangeAuthorization** delegate method like this.

```
switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            //Ask for permission
            break
        case .restricted:
            // user retricted to use location service.(Ex: parental control)
            break
        case .denied:
            //user denied location service
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            //always allow
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // when in use
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am always getting "authorizedAlways" even though I set "Allow while in use"

Comment: @Sridhar Could you share the exact code you're trying to execute? Might help ascertain the exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request explicitly via `CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization)) and listen as stated by [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423523-authorizationstatus) in delegate callback

> Important
>
> Use of authorizationStatus() is unnecessary and discouraged. Instead,
>   implement the locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:) delegate
>   callback to receive up-to-date authorization status.

Listen in delegate will give you possibility always be informed about any run-time changes of authorization status and make corresponding handling.