# How to check if the iOS permission is set to "Allow always"? [codenameone]

Tags: codenameone

For iOS, is it possible - (in cn1) to check if location permissions are set to "Allow always"?

Latest iOS versions are very annoying with all location permissions workflow. So if the user didn't set the location permission to Allow Always, I would like to notify her/him that certain features for the app won't be available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have that API. You can probably write native code similar to the one in this answer: [iOS 13 How to check user is given only Always allow location permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006139/ios-13-how-to-check-user-is-given-only-always-allow-location-permission)

But it seems Apple discourages this and recommends that you ask for an extended permission after you already got the first permission. I think that's a bit awkward. Either way, both can be implemented in native code.